# Show modal automatically if theres a query parameter in url Vue

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

Is there a way to open a modal automatically by first evaluate the URL for parameters?

For example:

Visitors to the site with URL : example.com don't see the modal. They just see the regular site.

Visitors to the site with URL example.com?token=abcd123 or example.com/token=abcd123 see the regular example.com site, but with a special modal over the top when the page loads.

How do you do this with vue?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Vue Router, you can extract the parameter from the route object.

`console.log(this.$route.query.token) // abcd123`

If you can extract it, you can see if `token` has any value, and if it does, display the modal. Do the logic inside the `mounted()` method.